# Stop serial terminal from putting prompt in middle of screen

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, serial-port, debian

I'm running Debian on a development board, which is connected to my main machine via a serial port. I connect to the serial port with `picocom` to get a Bash prompt.

The problem is that only the top 24 lines of the terminal get used; the bash prompt appears in the middle of the terminal and "full-screen" applications like `less` and `vim` are under-sized.

When I disconnect `picocom`, the terminal remains in this state until I use `reset`. If I then re-connect with `picocom`, the full terminal is used until I run something like `less`. So I guess the terminal driver on the Debian board is sending some control character that sets the terminal's number of rows.

Can I stop this from happening without breaking `less`/`vim`/etc?

Comment: `shopt -s checkwinsize`?

Comment: Ah, that fixed it. It looks like that causes bash to set $LINES and $COLUMNS, which I guess other applications read..

Comment: Er.. actually no it didn't, not sure what appeared to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`shopt -s checkwinsize`?
                    – 4ae1e1

Ah, that fixed it. – Brendan